# Arrays for Swift2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2

I have two seperate .swift files. And I want to use ManagePerson.swift to manage my `Strings` such as adding and retrieving. The other ViewController.swift creates an array of ManagePerson class for accessing the data.

In my ManagePerson.swift

```
func addPerson(name: String, code: String, description: String){
    self.name = name
    self.code = code
    self.description = description
}
```

In my ViewController.swift.

```
var personList = [PersonTable]() // Declared at class level

for jsonObjectString in resultArray! {
    let name = jsonObjectString["Name"] as! String
    let code = jsonObjectString["Code"] as! String
    let description = jsonObjectString["Description"] as! String
    self.personList[count].addPerson(Name, code: code, description: description)
    count++
}
```

However, I can't seem to perform `.addPerson` method. I get an error of "Thread: 6: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's imagine you  defined your "person" class with (a) three properties; and (b) an `init` method to set these properties:

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    let code: String
    let description: String

    init(name: String, code: String, description: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.code = code
        self.description = description
    }
}
```

Then, to instantiate a `Person`, it's just

```
let person = Person(name: "Joe Montana", code: "16", description: "Quarterback")
```

If you want an array of these `Person` objects, you define it as:

```
var personList = [Person]()
```

And thus, to add a `Person` to this array, it is:

```
personList.append(Person(name: "Joe Montana", code: "16", description: "Quarterback"))
```

So, if `resultArray` is an array of dictionaries, you add items like so:

```
for dictionary in resultArray! {
    let name = dictionary["Name"] as! String
    let code = dictionary["Code"] as! String
    let description = dictionary["Description"] as! String
    personList.append(Person(name: name, code: code, description: description))
}
```

But, note, we don't have to mess with `count` (as you can just add to the array).

Or, if these values could be `nil`, you'd define these as optionals:

```
class Person {
    let name: String?
    let code: String?
    let description: String?

    init(name: String?, code: String?, description: String?) {
        self.name = name
        self.code = code
        self.description = description
    }
}
```

and

```
for dictionary in resultArray! {
    let name = dictionary["Name"] as? String
    let code = dictionary["Code"] as? String
    let description = dictionary["Description"] as? String
    personList.append(Person(name: name, code: code, description: description))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `self.personList[count]` is `nil` it doesn't contain any instance of `PersonTable`